# Download 64 Bit Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, 64-bit

I downloaded the default python 3 from python.org, and I have been happy with it, but now I need to let python be able to use all of my RAM. I have read that a 64 bit installation will work. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can download 64 bit Python from this link [here](https://www.python.org/downloads/windows/). Select the option you want but make sure it has x86-64 in the name, meaning it is the 32 bit instruction set for a 64 bit machine.